# html float stacking order

Tags: html, css

I have tree elements I'd like floated,

```
<div class="title">Name</div>
<div class="description">slogan</div>
<div class="navbar"></div>
```

Css is:

```
.title, .description{
float:left;
}
.navbar{
float:right;
}
```

I'd like for the site description to sit underneath the title before the navbar does.

So, I know my html is wrong, The two float lefts should be in their own div and that div should have a percentage width so that it forces them to stack, but setting a width is not something I'd like to do as it's limiting what can be entered. Ideally I just need three inline elements so their width can be dynamic.

Thanks!
Jesse.

EDIT:

Here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fLw8xac0/1/

As you can see the nav bar stacks first

Comment: Hello. Can you provide us a JSFiddle ? It will be better for us to test solution, and see your problem. And BTW, welcome to StackOverflow !

Comment: Where's the trees? And btw, only dead trees float. At least on water.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the `.description` under `.navbar` and remove `float`.

```
<style>
    .title {float: left;}
    .navbar {float: right;}
</style>

<div class="title">Name</div>
<div class="navbar"></div>
<div class="description">slogan</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fvqx6z3f/

Comment: It took me a while to figure that one out! works great though. Thank you.

Comment: It works mostly! but if the description has more then 1 word the text wraps and looks strange. If I apply no-wrap to the white space, the floats essentially ignore it. any ideas?

Comment: @JesseBaker: So add `white-space: nowrap`

Answer (score 0):

You should put a wrapper div on the title and description divs and set the float on the wrapper.

[https://jsfiddle.net/8dpmfcf5/](https://jsfiddle.net/8dpmfcf5)

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
      <div class="title">Name</div>
      <div class="description">slogan</div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar">nav</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
  .wrap{
    float:left;
  }
  .navbar{
    float:right;
  }
```